# Swift: task.arguments ignoring slashes

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I'm making an app that installs printer and downloads file but it can't download the file because `NStask` ignoring slashes and it cause my app get stuck in downloading for infinite

```
task.arguments = ["curl -o /Users/printer.ppd https://example.com/printer.ppd"]
```

If I made wrong command, the error returned. As you can see, it ignored the slashes

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl -o printer.ppd https
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the path to the command is supposed to be the `launchPath` of the task:

```
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/curl"
```

and the (space separated) `arguments` must be an **array** of strings:

```
task.arguments = ["-o",  
                  "/Users/printer.ppd",           
                  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juskdtlm/juskdtlm.github.io/master/printer.ppd"]
```